# Removing the Default Wrap Character From all records

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I am using BizTalk 2009 and I have a flat file that is similar to the following

"0162892172","TIM   ","LastName   ","760    ","  ","COMANCHE     ","LN "

"0143248282","GEORGE  ","LastName   ","625   ","  ","ENID     ","AVE "

When I parse it and start mapping it I need to get rid of the quotation marks. I have marked the Wrap Character attribute for the schema as a quotation mark but it doesn't remove it when BizTalk is parsing the file.

Is there an easy way to specify the removal of a wrap character or am I going to have to run it through a script functiod every time? Also I would like to be able to remove the trailing spaces as well, if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're still seeing the quotes after parsing, it likely means you set the wrap character property incorrectly. Are you sure you also set Wrap Character Type == Character?

As for the extra spaces, those will be hard to get rid of during parsing, because the quotes would specifically tell bts that they were intentional, so yeah, your best bet is to probably remove those during mapping or whatever.

Comment: Ah.. My problem was I hadn't turned the Child Record to use 'Default Wrap Character'.

Answer (score 1):

[this page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/biztalkgeneral/thread/80e3f423-e53f-4bb2-aaa5-f2a1da44637a) seems to suggest that removing the trailing spaces can be done with:

```
> Pad Character Type = Hexadecimal
> Pad Character = 0x20
```